# How to Add data in tbody using Javascript only

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

This is my Javascript function:

```
function SaveCustomdata() {
    var customName = document.getElementById("lblNAME").value;
    var customEmail = document.getElementById("lblEmail").value;
    var customContectNo = document.getElementById("lblContectNO").value;


    var row = "";
    row += '<tr><td>' + customName + '</td><td>' + customEmail + '</td><td>' + customContectNo + '</td></tr>';

    document.getElementById("Customdata").appendChild(row);
}
```

HTML code where I want to append the data:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style=" color:#01A0DF; padding-right:60px;">Name</th>
            <th style=" color:#01A0DF; padding-right:70px;">Email</th>
            <th style=" color:#01A0DF; padding-right:90px;">Contect/Mobile No</th>
            <td>

                <input type="button" id="btnclick" value="Add" onclick="AddRecord()" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="Customdata"></tbody>
</table>
```

Getting an error:

> 0x800a139e - JavaScript run time error: Hierarchy Request Error

Comment: You need to pass an element to `appendChild()` not a string. (Use `document.createElement("tr")` first to create one, update it, append it)

Comment: You actually have to create the elements with JS. You can't just append a string like you can with jQuery. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp

Comment: @Gavin http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Hello sir could you show me an example for this @ Alex k

Comment: You can use .innerHTML = row instead of .appendChild(row). This will replace the whole table body though. If you afterwards want to append something, you have to first get the innerHTML and append your string to that, before you do .innerHTML = row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the use of innerHTML:

```
function SaveCustomdata() {
    var customName = document.getElementById("lblNAME").value;
    var customEmail = document.getElementById("lblEmail").value;
    var customContectNo = document.getElementById("lblContectNO").value;

    var row = "";
    row += '<tr><td>' + customName + '</td><td>' + customEmail + '</td><td>' + customContectNo + '</td></tr>';

    // get the current table body html as a string, and append the new row
    var html = document.getElementById("Customdata").innerHTML + row;

    // set the table body to the new html code
    document.getElementById("Customdata").innerHTML = html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L89uk91r/2/). Let us know if it helped you a bit.
Basically you could use `.innerHTML` for appending strings as elements, because this gets "evaluated by browser".
Otherwise you would have to do it programmatically as mentioned in the comments